# MySQL (in Laravel): How do I select a column's count before applying a "group by" and then select another column's count after applying a "group by"

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I know this question might sound confusing. Let me use an example to illustrate.

Say right now I have `4 tables: tags, posts, replies, and post_tag` (for the many-many relationship between posts and tags).

Now I want to count both the `number of posts and number of replies per tag`.

To count the number of posts per tag is easy, which would simply be something like:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    posts
inner join post_tag
    on posts.id = post_tag.post_id
inner join tags
    on tags.id = post_tag.tag_id
```

Similarly, to count # of replies per tag is also very easy. However, how would I use ONE single query to get all the tags with their post count and replies count at the same time?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result (as tabular text)

Comment: Could you please take a look at the other question that is the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905402/laravel-eloquent-how-to-count-with-nested-relationship