# Laravel Eloquent: How to count with nested relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say we have four tables: tags, posts, replies, and post_tag

```
tags table:

id  tag
1   tag A
2   tag B
3   tag C
```

```
posts table:

id  post_content
1   some text A
2   some text B
3   some text C
```

```
post_tag table: (for many-many relationship between posts and tags)

post_id  tag_id
1        1
1        2
2        3
```

```
replies table:

id  post_id
1   1
2   1
3   2
```

Now I wish to generate a table which gives me the total replies count for each of the tag.
A sample output based on the above tables would be:

```
id  tag_id  replies_count
1   1       2
2   2       2
3   3       1
```

I already have a relationship between tag and posts, but is there any way for me to generate a relationship on tags that would give me all the replies for a tag? Something like

```
function replies() {
   return $this->posts()->replies()
}
```

Last but not least, I would wish to get one step further beyond this: the final table I wish to get would be a table with both post count and replies count for each of the tags

```
id  tag_id  posts_count  replies_count
1   1       1             2
2   2       1             2 
3   3       1             1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new relationship method in your **Tag** model, you could attach a "replies" relationship automatically to your **Post** model using `$with` attribute. Whenever you fetch all the posts related to that tags, it will include all the replies related to that post as well.

I would not recommend creating a table just to count the replies of a tag, you can do that on the client side by utilizing the response data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I am still confused about this. I know I can get all the replies for a post, but how can I get all the replies for a tag? Could you please give me some more details on this

Comment: Seems that these "replies" are not directly related to your Tag model, instead it is related to Post. In other words, all the replies that that is attached in a Post is automatically related to the Tag as Laravel only fetches records related to the model using the foreign key, in this case its `post_id`. So to make the story short, if you merge all the replies attached to the posts related to a tag, those are the replies of the tag you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! Yes I can get all the replies for a tag by loading the replies from the related posts for that tag. But this would require a for loop, where I aggregate all the replies_count for all the related posts. What I would wish to achieve is to use Laravel Eloquent relationship for this. Would there be a way to do this?

Comment: I think you could use Query builder for that, but if you would like a traditional way, you can for-loop them and a better approach, make it more generic and put it inside a helper function so that it can be reused to other relationships.